# Why is activeNetwork null? (in android)

Tags: android, networking

Check the network status in the Activity onStart method.

This is my source.

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    if (!NetworkManager.checkNetworkState(this))
        showDialog("")
}

object NetworkManager {
    fun checkNetworkState(context: Context): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

        val nw = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
        val actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw) ?: return false
        return when {
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

The location of the problem is here.
val nw = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false

It occurs intermittently in the following situations.
ActiveNetwork is null when changed from background to foreground.
but, I connected the network and I have permission

my device API is Android 11

Do you know why is activeNetwork null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Do you know why is activeNetwork null?
```

When it returns null, it means that your device is not connected to the internet at all

getActiveNetwork()
Returns a Network object corresponding to the currently active default data network.

You can read more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but, I connected the network...